# What is the difference between &lt; and lt when comparing values in XSLT?

Tags: date, xslt

I am trying to figure out what is the difference between &lt; and  lt  when comparing two values in XSLT.

Assuming the XML looks like below:

```
<root>
    <field time="PT22M00.000S" value="red" number="22"/>
    <field2 time="PT23M00.000S" value="blue" number="23"/>
</root>
```

I will get the following results for each expression:

- Comparing dates:
  `if (xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field/@time) lt xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field2/@time)) then (/root/field/@value) else (/root/field2/@value)`

*The result is "red"*

- Comparing numbers:
  `if (/root/field/@number &lt; /root/field2/@number) then (/root/field/@value) else (/root/field2/@value)`

*The result is "red"*

- Comparing dates using < :
  `if (xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field/@time) &lt; xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field2/@time)) then (/root/field/@value) else (/root/field2/@value)`

*The result is "blue"*

Are there any explanations between the differences between these two?
Thanks!

Comment: *The result is "blue"* Not when I try it: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aixRuz

Comment: Don't be frightened of reading the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-comparisons

Comment: My guess is that you are running this with `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" ...>`

Replace the value of the `version` attribute with `"2.0"` or greater and then all results will be "red" as expected.

In the XPath 2.0 specification there are special rules for the semantics of the general comparison operators (such as `<`) when evaluated in "XPath 1.0 compatibility mode"

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Obviously you didn't try hard enough :)

Comment: No, it did not occur to me that a stylesheet that uses `xs:dayTimeDuration()` would have `version="1.0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Comparing dates using < : `if (xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field/@time) &lt; xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field2/@time)) then (/root/field/@value) else (/root/field2/@value)`
>
> *The result is "blue"*
>
> Are there any explanations between the differences between these two?
> Thanks!

**Short answer**:

The above result is produced when an XSLT 1.0 (`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" ...>`) transformation is applied. Replace the value of the version attribute with "2.0" or greater and then all results will be "red" as expected.

**Long answer**:

When an XSLT 2.0 processor is executing an XSLT 1.0 transformation, this is done in **[XPath 1.0 compatibility mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-compatibility-mode)** .

In particular, **[here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-general-comparisons)** is the definition of the semantics of a general comparison (including `<`) in XPath 1.0 compatibility mode:

> If XPath 1.0 compatibility mode is true, a general comparison is
> evaluated by applying the following rules, in order:
>
> 1. If either operand is a single atomic value that is an instance of
>    xs:boolean, then the other operand is converted to xs:boolean by
>    taking its effective boolean value.
> 2. Atomization is applied to each operand. After atomization, each
>    operand is a sequence of atomic values.
> 3. If the comparison operator is <, <=, >, or >=, then each item in both
>    of the operand sequences is converted to the type xs:double by
>    applying the fn:number function. (Note that fn:number returns the
>    value NaN if its operand cannot be converted to a number.)

This is exactly what happens.

The two dates are converted to numbers and this results in `NaN` in both cases.

And by definition, `NaN < NaN` is `false()`

**To prove this, run the following XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "if (xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field/@time)
       lt xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field2/@time))
        then string(/root/field/@value)
        else string(/root/field2/@value)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "if (/root/field/@number &lt; /root/field2/@number)
        then string(/root/field/@value)
        else string(/root/field2/@value)"/>
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "if (xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field/@time) 
      &lt; xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field2/@time))
        then string(/root/field/@value)
        else string(/root/field2/@value)"/>
===============================================

    <xsl:sequence select="xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field/@time) 
                     &lt; xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field2/@time)"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="v1" select="data(xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field/@time))"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$v1"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="v2" select="data(xs:dayTimeDuration(/root/field2/@time))"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$v2"/>
    
    <xsl:sequence select="$v1 &lt; $v2"/>
================================================

     <xsl:sequence select="number($v1)"/>
     <xsl:sequence select="number($v2)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <field time="PT22M00.000S" value="red" number="22"/>
    <field2 time="PT23M00.000S" value="blue" number="23"/>
</root>
```

**the result is**:

```
red red blue
===============================================

    false PT22M PT23M false
================================================

     NaN NaN
```

exactly as it should be, as per the explanation above.

We also get this from Saxon, essentially telling us that XPath 1.0 compatibility mode was indeed used:

> *Saxon 9.1.0.1J from Saxonica*
> *Java version 1.8.0_191*
> *Warning: at xsl:stylesheet on line 2 column 46 of xxxx.xsl*:
> ***Running an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet with an XSLT 2.0 processor***

Now, in the same transformation replace the `version="1.0"` attribute with "`version="2.0"` and run the transformation.

**The result now is**:

```
red red red
===============================================

    true PT22M PT23M true
================================================

     NaN NaN
```

Just because the XSLT processor executed the transformation as a true XSLT 2.0 one!